# Steelseries Engine not detecting MSI GE62 Apache Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Just got the new MSI GE62 Apache 002, however when I launch the Steelseries Engine, version 3 it says no devices connected. I have the latest drivers installed and the KLM software works as it should, so what is the probelm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a Windows Update and now it works

Comment: I am still facing this issue. Did windows update but still the same. Please help.

Comment: FYI - I have windows 10

Answer (score -1):

To get this to work for me, I had to update the device driver:

- Open Device Manager
- Open Keyboards
- Right click "SteelSeries PS/2 Keyboard"
- "Update Driver Software"
- "Search automatically for updated driver software"
- After that process finished, restart Windows

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future.

Comment: How does this differ from simply running Windows Update?

Comment: It really shouldn't, but in my case Windows Update alone wasn't updating this driver.